# How to test concurrency using py.test

Tags: python, concurrency, pytest, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to test a thread safety of a function using py.test 
My efforts:

```
def function_to_be_tested(arg1,arg2):
   some functionality

class Test:
   def setup()
   def teardown()
   def test_conc()
       p1=Process(taget=function_to_be_tested,args(arg1,arg2,))
       p2=Process (taget=function_to_be_tested,args(arg1,arg3,))
       p1.start()
       p2.start()
       p1.join()
       p2.join()
```

excute above file using py.test commad. 
 This shows following error.

```
ExceptionPexpect: isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?
```

Can you help me to decode this error and also give a guidance on how to do this.

Thanks
Here is the actual code I am trying and stacktrace:

```
import pytest
from multiprocessing import Process
from pexpect import pxssh

def func(cls,b):
    cls.s.sendline("bteq")
    cls.s.prompt()
    print b
    #some operations inside the bteq session

class Test:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.s=pxssh.pxssh()
        cls.s.login("IP",'Username','Pwd')
    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.s.logout()
        print "teardown"

    def test_1(cls):
        p1=Process(target=func,args=(cls,13,))
        p2=Process(target=func,args=(cls,46,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

stack trace:

```
dipakw@dipakw-Inspiron-3558:~$ py.test -v -s test.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/dipakw, inifile: 
plugins: xdist-1.15.0
collected 1 items 

test.py::Test::test_1 Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dipakw/test.py", line 7, in func
    cls.s.prompt()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 352, in prompt
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dipakw/test.py", line 7, in func
    cls.s.prompt()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 352, in prompt
    i = self.expect([self.PROMPT, TIMEOUT], timeout=timeout)
    i = self.expect([self.PROMPT, TIMEOUT], timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1418, in expect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1418, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1433, in expect_list
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1433, in expect_list
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1502, in expect_loop
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
    c = self.read_nonblocking(self.maxread, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1502, in expect_loop
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 886, in read_nonblocking
    if not self.isalive():
    c = self.read_nonblocking(self.maxread, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1220, in isalive
    'on our process?')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 886, in read_nonblocking
    if not self.isalive():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1220, in isalive
ExceptionPexpect: isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?
    'on our process?')
ExceptionPexpect: isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?
```

Comment: Show full Traceback

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of the below for testing concurrency / threads:

```
import threading
from functools import partial


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_is_concurrency_safe():        
    # setup anything for the test...

    # recreate multiple threads calling the same function at the same time
   _call_concurrently(
        partial(my_function, args),
        partial(my_function, args),
    )

    # Test that the race condition didn't create duplicates, etc

def _call_concurrently(*callables):
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=callable_) for callable_ in callables]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```